# Direction vector: Correctly scale sin(radians(x)) + cos(radians(z)) with y axis

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, vector, 3d

I have an issue with the directional transform math for a voxel raytracer I'm working on in Python. X axis is left-right, Y axis is up-down, Z axis is forward-backward: I calculate view direction from a camera angle stored in degrees, direction being the virtual arrow the point of view points toward: Z rotation translates to X and Z directions, Y rotation to Y direction, X rotation is ignored as I didn't implement camera rolling. The conversion is done by running the rotation radians through a sine / cosine, for example: Rotation `x = 0, y = 90, z = 45` becomes direction `x = 0.7071067811865475, y = 1.0, z = 0.7071067811865475` since a 45* angle for rot Z means dir X and Z equally point toward that direction. A simple demo to visualize what I'm doing.

```
angle_y = 90
for angle_z in (0, 45, 90, 135, 180, 225, 270, 315, 360):
    dir_x = math.sin(math.radians(angle_z))
    dir_y = math.sin(math.radians(angle_y))
    dir_z = math.cos(math.radians(angle_z))
    print("x: " + str(dir_x) + " y: " + str(dir_y) + " z: " + str(dir_z))
```

Directions X and Z work as intended and form a perfect arch at every rotation as `angle_z` goes from 0* to 360*. The issue is the Y direction: If you're looking straight ahead and it has a value of 0 everything works fine. But as you look up and down, the Y direction needs to correctly shrink the magnitude of X and Z with its intensity, otherwise extra "force" is added to the total direction which should never exceed X + Z as defined by their sin + cos. Therefore the following is wrong:

```
return dir_x, dir_y, dir_z
```

I tried the simplest solution which is a lot more accurate:

```
return dir_x * (1 - abs(dir_y)), dir_y, dir_z * (1 - abs(dir_y))
```

But this too causes incorrect perspective: As I look up or down it looks like the world shrinks vertically. I get an even more correct result by dividing `dir_y` by two:

```
return dir_x * (1 - abs(dir_y) / 2), dir_y, dir_z * (1 - abs(dir_y) / 2)
```

This stops the world from bending at first, but as you look closer to a full -90 / +90 angle up or down it makes everything bend like a concave mirror. What is the correct way to shrink X and Z with by the intensity of Y to get a direction arrow that correctly maintains magnitude?

Comment: I don't understand what kind of coordinate system you are using here. Why not just use spherical polar coordinates (1,a,b) to give you a camera direction unit vector (sin(a)cos(b), sin(a)sin(b), cos(a))?

Comment: I'm not sure how that would look like. What I need works best using angles: I'm simply converting rotation to a direction to obtain the virtual arrow the point is pointing toward. Thankfully an answer was provided and my approach works correctly now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As proposed in comment, use spherical polar coordinates with your angles.

> But as you look up and down, the Y direction needs to correctly shrink the magnitude of X and Z with its intensity

In your words you "shrink" your X and Z values by `cos(angle_y)`

```
dir_x = math.sin(math.radians(angle_z)) * math.cos(math.radians(angle_y))
dir_y = math.sin(math.radians(angle_y))
dir_z = math.cos(math.radians(angle_z)) * math.cos(math.radians(angle_y))
```

Using [image: sin^2 + cos^2 = 1] you can check it's always a unit vector

Comment: Worked like a charm, can't believe I missed it... thanks!